# What is 0.1 converted to 8bit IEEE754?

Tags: floating-point

0.1 via $32\text{ bit}$ [is rather easy](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html):

Sign: $0_2 = 0_{10}$

Exponent: $123_{10} = 01111011_2$

Mantissa: $5033165_{10} = 100110011001100110011001101_2$

Now, how do you calculate this, if you've only $8\text{ bit}$ available?
**Sign: $1\text{ bit}$, Exponent: $2\text{ bit}$, Mantissa: $5\text{ bit}$**

My idea: $S=0; E=01; M=00001$

What do you think?

Comment: There is no 754 standard for 8 bit mini-floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using analogy of IEEE 754 standard. We see the only difference is about size. Yours is 8-bit while IEEE 754 is 32-bit for single precision and 64-bit for double precision.

Let's play with your own standard format that still using IEEE 754 analogy:

```
sign (1-bit) | exponent (2-bit) | mantissa (5-bit)
```

- `Sign = 0` since `0.1` is positive.

Integer part:
0. = 0 in binary

Fraction part:

```
.1 * 2 = .2 + 0
.2 * 2 = .4 + 0
.4 * 2 = .8 + 0
.8 * 2 = .6 + 1
.6 * 2 = .2 + 1
.2 * 2 = .4 + 0 (back to the second equation)
...
```

So the fraction part is:

```
0001100110011...
```

Now combine integer part and fraction part

```
0.0001100110011...
```

Now represent it with using scientific notation

```
0.0001100110011 = 1.100110011 * 2 ^ (-4)
```

From scientific notation we got normalized mantissa that is `100110011`. Since your mantissa standard size is 5-bit we need to truncate it into 5-bit hence the mantissa is `10011`.

From scientific notation we got also `exponen = -4`. Since your exponent size is 2-bit we need to find offset of exponent bias first. `01 is considered as 0` so the offset is 1 hence
`1 + (-4) = -3` . This is underflow!!! Due to your exponent size is too small, but let force it.

```
01 = 0
00 = -1
11 = -2 (back to the 11 due to underflow)
10 = -3 (we will take this)
```

With using your standard format we get:

```
sign (1-bit) | exponent (2-bit) | mantissa (5-bit)
0 | 10 | 10011
Or
01010011
```

Undeflow happened because your standard to represent 0.1 is too small. If it's me it depends on case i will face. I mean If the case care precision then I extend more mantissa size, If the case care higher range or lower range I extend the exponent size.

Answer (score 2):

For $8$-bit floating point, you should look at $A$-law and $\mu$-law encoding standards:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-law_algorithm

Depending on your input range, you may need some scaling.